# Best way for substring replace in haskell

Tags: haskell, substring, replace

The problem is quite simple: I have to replace all occurences of "fooo" and all its substrings with "xyz". In Java, for example, I will do it like this:

```
someString.replaceAll( "fooo|foo|fo", "xyz" )
```

and it will do the trick. But in Haskell I've found no efficient way to work with regex. First of all, I've read this: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Regular_expressions

The only library which actually has `replace` function is regex-posix, but its considered "very slow" in performance. And this fact is not acceptable. Also I've found that this `replace` function for any reasons doesn't respect the order of patterns given, so I've got output like this:

```
>replace "boo fooo boo" "xyz"
"boo xyzoo boo"
```

Other backends don't imply such functionality.

So I decided to write simple workaround:

```
replaceFoo input =
    helper input []
    where
        helper ('f':'o':'o':'o':xs) ys = helper xs ("zyx" ++ ys)
        helper ('f':'o':'o':xs) ys = helper xs ("zyx" ++ ys)
        helper ('f':'o':xs) ys = helper xs ("zyx" ++ ys)
        helper (x:xs) ys = helper xs (x:ys)
        helper [] ys = reverse ys
```

Whilst I don't find this function nice, it works well and fast. But for now I met the necessity to add more words in this replacor, and I don't like the idea to extend `helper` patterns anymore (I need to say that I actually have 4 words in it in real app and that's odd).

I'll be happy if someone help me with *fast* solution.

---

[cebewee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647987/cebewee), thanks for the Data.String.Utils. But I fear this approach is quite slow if there are many words to replace ("fooo" to "xyz", "foo" to "xyz", "fo" to "xyz", "bar" to "quux" and so on), because to get that to work I will need to `foldr (\str (from,to) -> replace from to str) input pairs` or something like that and it will take O(n*n). More than that, it may have unexpected result of replacing substring of result of previous replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex-xmlschema package has a **sed** function that might be what you're looking for:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-xmlschema-0.1.3

See particularly:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-xmlschema/0.1.3/doc/html/Text-Regex-XMLSchema-String.html#v:sed

There was a discussion of options for string rewriting on Haskell-Cafe last year:

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-May/077943.html

Comment: The URL http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-May/077943.html now gives "Not Found"

Answer (score 7):

There is [Data.String.Utils.replace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.1.0.3/doc/html/Data-String-Utils.html) in the MissingH package. If you only need plain substring replace (and not regular expressions), this might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The [replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec) package allows you to
search for pattern matches and then edit the found matches. Here is a solution using
[`Replace.Megaparsec.streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit).

```hs
>>> import Replace.Megaparsec
>>> import Text.Megaparsec.Char
>>> streamEdit (chunk "fooo" <|> chunk "foo" <|> chunk "fo") (const "xyz") "boo fooo boo"
"boo xyz boo"
```